# ng-filter with filter is not filtering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

hi I'm trying to filter a list of objects in an array and displaying it. The filtering is based on the users input from an input field.

I've had a look at number of questions on Stackoverflow, but I feel this is different- since my data is already in an array. 
Html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input ng-model="search" type="text"
        placeholder="Filter by" autofocus>
    </form>
    <div ng-repeat="f in feedbacklist | filter:search ">
      <div>{{f.jobId}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.search = "";
$scope.feedbacklist = [
                {
                    jobId: "1432",
                    feedbackId: "342342",
                    profileUrl: "assets/img/profiles/avatar_small2x.jpg",
                    address: "24 Mathers St, Smithswood",
                    name: "Jorem Ipsum",
                    initials: "JP",
                    content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
                    date: "23/05/2016",
                    message: "",
                    replies: [
                        {
                            jobId: "1232",
                            feedbackId: "342342",
                            profileUrl: "assets/img/profiles/avatar_small2x.jpg",
                            address: "24 Mathers St, Smithswood",
                            name: "Jorem Ipsum",
                            initials: "JP",
                            content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
                            date: "23/05/2016",
                        },
                        {
                            jobId: "1232",
                            feedbackId: "342342",
                            profileUrl: "assets/img/profiles/avatar_small2x.jpg",
                            address: "24 Mathers St, Smithswood",
                            name: "Jorem Ipsum",
                            initials: "JP",
                            content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
                            date: "23/05/2016",
                        }
                    ],

                },
                {
                    jobId: "1232",
                    feedbackId: "342342",
                    profileUrl: "",
                    address: "24 Mathers St, Smithswood",
                    name: "Jorem Ipsum",
                    initials: "JP",
                    content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
                    date: "23/05/2016",
                    message: "",
                    replies: [

                    ],

                },

            ];



});
```

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2stbsqt/4/)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Also, your JSFiddle had some issues. Fixed here ~ http://jsfiddle.net/z2stbsqt/5/

Comment: Its not working in my code for some reason... The data structure is exactly the same as what's on here. What did you fix up in the fiddle ? and Thank you.

Comment: You can't include the `<body>` tag. I also moved the script to run in *"No wrap - in <body>"*

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code don't find any issue with your code. The only thing I want to know is on which property in the object you want to filter?

If you want to filter it by 'JobId' then use this code 
`filter:{jobId:search}`

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z2stbsqt/8/)